# Adding upper subscript on conditional ifelse in R

Tags: r, if-statement, case-when, subscript

I'm struggling to format `Name` column in such a way that it adds an upper subscript when the `Value` column is larger than 10. Any suggestions? Here is a sample dataset.

```
 tibble(Name = LETTERS[1:10], 
        Value = sample(5:15,10))
```

The result should be like this:
`A^1` when Value is greater then 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed(123)
d <- tibble(Name = LETTERS[1:10], 
       Value = sample(5:15,10)) %>%
  mutate(Name = if_else(Value>10, paste0(Name, "^1"), Name))


library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(Name, Value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
 scale_x_discrete("Axis label", labels = parse(text = d$Name)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(vjust=0))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, thank you, but I want to have actual subscript so when I plot it using ggplot I will have nice looking upper subscript

Comment: That wasnt too clear, there was no mention of ggplot in your question. The answer will depend on which plot you want to make.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that and thank you for the answer :)